# Best 2010 Content Query Web Part

Tags: content-query-web-part

There are already a whole lot of query/roll up webparts from 3rd party vendors on the market. Evaluating each on of these though is very time consuming. I'd therefore appreciate anybody sharing their experience with these webparts.

In paticular I'm looking for a content query/roll up webpart which should meet the following requirments:

- Query all lists inside a site colection using a certain custom content type
- Filter by audiences and people picker field with multiple entries enabled
- Look & feel very similar to the standard SP2010 list look & feel

Answer (score 2):

I have tried few of these for SharePoint 2007, and we also did some custom web parts for similar purposes. After long research my No. 1 choice is [Lightning Conductor Web Part](http://www.lightningtools.com/list-rollup-web-parts.aspx).